# Python 2.x, appending a PriorityQueue with another PriorityQueue

Tags: python, queue, append

I am using Queue.PriorityQueue() in my problem in which I have several PriorityQueue() objects that I would like to append together by the priority based element.

All the PriorityQueue() objects have the same type in tuples that the PriorityQueue() objects are composed of.

Is there are a way (a pythonic way?) to do this without having to write my own code for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
def merge_queues(queues):    
    result_queue = PriorityQueue()
    for queue in queues:
        while not queue.empty():
            result_queue.put(queue.get())
    return result_queue
```

Comment: I was hoping that if we could append two queues together like append two Lists together (l1 + l2) but if there isn't any built-in support for this with PriorityQueue then I will use your snippet for this.